# Fos Userbundle min password length and email check

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed fos Userbundle with symfony 3.2.8, I want to force a user to have a min length for his password on change, if a admin on back office create a user i want to have a min password length. I want to check if admin on backoffice have write a good mail address like xx@xx.xx. I have create a form for the backoffice. How to do this ? 
Create a model and put assert on the field on model and got values to create a new user ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use assert like this :

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 * )
 */
protected $name;
```

Comment: thanks but on the user entity (override ?) or on a model for the form ?

Comment: in the user entity and do not forget
 to use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;